# Google Analytics Java API "401 Unauthorized Login Required" error

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I try to get data from GA using java libs and service account. I`ve made all required settings: activate Analytics API in Cloud console, generate service account, get private key, add generated developer e-mail with read rights in GA user management.

With my local implementation this works fine. But when I try to run same code from server side I receive status "401 Unauthorized Login Required". Both implementations use Java 5 runtime, Google API services Java libs version 1.17.0 rev75.

The code snippet with credentials definition:

```
    HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();    

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId("xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("privatekey.p12"))
    .build();
```

The Analytics object and query builder:

```
Analytics analytics = new Analytics.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
.setApplicationName("MyApp")
.build();

Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:123", "2013-12-09","2013-12-09", "ga:visits");
HttpResponse response = apiQuery.executeUnparsed();
```

I`ve added httpLogger to compare traffic. I see that in case of local and server runs the authorization flow is same, no problems with getting access token.

With local run I`ve received response with status 200:

```
    CONFIG: -------------- RESPONSE --------------
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
    ETag: "xxxx"
    Date: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 13:12:32 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
    Content-Length: 1728
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Expires: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 13:12:32 GMT
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Server: GSE
{JSON BODY}
```

But with server run I`ve recieved response with status 401:

```
CONFIG: -------------- RESPONSE --------------
401 Unauthorized
date: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 13:17:32 GMT
alternate-protocol: 443:quic
server: GSE
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest"
transfer-encoding: chunked
expires: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 13:17:32 GMT
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
cache-control: private, max-age=0
    {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

Could anybody help me? I`ve really checked everything I know but no luck.

**EDIT**
Does anybody know if delegation of domain-wide authority to service account is relevant to Google Analytics API?

Best regards,
Sergey.

Comment: I see the code that creates the credentials object - could you also share the code uses that object to create the API request?

Comment: Hi @aeijdenberg ! Thanks for your answer. I`ve added the Analytics object and query code to main post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by changing transport to ApacheHttpTransport class.

But it will be quite useful to get to know whats wrong with NetHttpTransport.

Regards, Sergey.